# C# Split ignore commas in input string

Tags: c#, split

So I've finished Huffman compression algorithm, but it will work only if a .txt file doesn't contain **, / ;**

So I want to ignore *only* these symbols

What I've got:

1. Dictionary of a character and its code, separated by comma. Each pair separated by **;**
2. **/** at the end of a dictionary (because next symbol is number of added zeros)

**Example:**
c,1;a,00;t,01;/3

Of course, when I type in file something like "I love dogs, cats", I've got problems:) Like this one: **System.FormatException: "String must be exactly one character long."**

Here's my code:

```
Dictionary<char, string> forDecoding = new Dictionary<char, string>();
    using (sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {

        string line = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string[] lines = line.Split('/');
        string[] dict = lines[0].Split(';');
        string[] item = null;

        foreach (var v in lines[0])
        {
            encoded.Add(v);
        }
        count = Convert.ToInt32(lines[1]);
        for (int i = 0; i < dict.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            item = dict[i].Split(',');
            forDecoding.Add(Convert.ToChar(item[0]), item[1]);
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to modify it in order to see that comma inside like another symbol of input information that has to be encoded?

Comment: @user9938 yes, this is the only one solution I came up with as well:( but thank you so much!

Comment: You need a more sophisticated way than string.split() to break up your input string.

Comment: @NicholasHunter for example?

Comment: You can look at the current character and either the previous char and/or the next character, to determine if the current character is a separator or a character that needs to be processed. Although, using a character sequence that is unlikely to occur in normal writing, as a separator--such as `~@`--is probably easier.

Comment: @user9938 yes, I tried to do so, but failed. Plus, unfortunately, I don't have enough time to throw away all pieces of code where I use Split and redo it with something more sophisticated. Guess I will just do like you've suggested. So thank you again:)

Comment: The real issue is that you want to parse the first string ('c,1;a,00;t,01;/3') differently from the second string ('I love dogs, cats'), In the first case, you want to treat the comma as a delimiter, in the second you want to handle it like any other character. So how do represent that difference in the code?

Comment: @NicholasHunter that's why I wrote here. I don't know how to represent it in code.

Comment: Can you provide some additional sample data?

Comment: @user9938 tell me what it is and I'll post it

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem and you have not posted enough code and sample data to reproduce it. Maybe this might help you craft an easier question to understand. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Dictionary<char, string> forDecoding = new Dictionary<char, string>();

                             ...

private void LoadEncodedData(string filename)
{
    //remove existing items
    forDecoding.Clear();

    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename))
    {

        int fileLength = 0;
        char previousChar = char.MinValue;
        char secondPreviousChar = char.MinValue;
        char dictKey = char.MinValue;
        string dictVal = string.Empty;
        bool isDictVal = false;
        bool isNextCharEOF = false;
        bool isNumberOfZeros = false;
        int numberOfAddedZeros = 0;
        string numberOfZerosStr = string.Empty;
        
       
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            //read char and move position
            char currentChar = (char)sr.Read();

            //read next char without moving position
            char nextChar = (char)sr.Peek();

            //65535 = EOF
            if (nextChar == 65535)
            {
                //set val
                isNextCharEOF = true;
            }

            if (!isNextCharEOF && !isDictVal && nextChar == ',')
            {
                //set value
                dictKey = currentChar;
            }
            else if (!isDictVal && previousChar == ',' && currentChar != ',')
            {
                //start saving chars for dictionary value
                dictVal = currentChar.ToString();

                //set value
                isDictVal = true;
            }
            else if (isDictVal && currentChar == ';')
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("dictKey: '" + dictKey.ToString() + "' dictVal: '" + dictVal + "'");

                //add to dictionary
                forDecoding.Add(dictKey, dictVal);

                //re-initialize
                dictVal = string.Empty;

                //set value
                isDictVal = false;
            }
            else if (isDictVal)
            {
                //append
                dictVal += currentChar.ToString();
            }
            else if (!isDictVal && secondPreviousChar == ';' && previousChar == '/' && currentChar != ',')
            {
                if (!isNextCharEOF)
                {
                    //set value
                    isNumberOfZeros = true;
                    numberOfZerosStr = currentChar.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    //set value
                    numberOfZerosStr = currentChar.ToString();

                    numberOfAddedZeros = 0;
                    Int32.TryParse(numberOfZerosStr, out numberOfAddedZeros);

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("    numberOfAddedZeros: " + numberOfAddedZeros + System.Environment.NewLine);

                    //set value
                    isNumberOfZeros = false;
                    numberOfZerosStr = string.Empty;
            
                }  
            }
            else if (isNumberOfZeros && (isNextCharEOF || nextChar != ','))
            {
                //append
                numberOfZerosStr += currentChar;

                numberOfAddedZeros = 0;
                Int32.TryParse(numberOfZerosStr, out numberOfAddedZeros);

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("    numberOfAddedZeros: " + numberOfAddedZeros + System.Environment.NewLine);

                //set value
                isNumberOfZeros = false;
                numberOfZerosStr = string.Empty;
            }
            else if (isNumberOfZeros)
            {
                //append
                numberOfZerosStr += currentChar;
            }

            //set value
            secondPreviousChar = previousChar;
            previousChar = currentChar;

            fileLength += 1; //increment
        }
    }
}
```

**Example data**: c,1;/,00;t,01;/3

Comment: Oh my God! You're a lifesaver! Thank you sooo much, sir, I understood this idea and code. You're incredible, thank you!:)